# Make a code repeat loop if user input a non-numeric character?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, numbers

**Goal:**

If the user enters a non-numeric number, make the loop run again.
Also is there another (more efficient) way of writing the numeric inputs?

```
public static void user_input (){
   int input;
   input = fgetc (System.in);
   while (input != '\n'){
      System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
      if (input == '0' == '1' ..... '9'){
          //Execute some code
      }
      else {
          System.out.println("Error Please Try Again");
          //Repeat While loop
      }
   }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I need the while loop condition. Simply asking, how do you repeat the while loop? Also no scanner methods.

Comment: Character.isDigit(); will check single character  number or not.

Answer (score 1):

Take the input using `next` instead of `nextInt`. Put a `try catch` to parse the input using `parseInt` method. If parsing is successful `break the while loop`, otherwise `continue`. Try this:

```
public static void user_input() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number.");
            String input = sc.next();
            int intInputValue = 0;
            try {
                intInputValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
                System.out.println("Correct input, exit");
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
                System.out.println("Input is not a number, continue");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
Enter a number.
w
Input is not a number, continue
Enter a number.
3
Correct input, exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

while(!userInput.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter again");
    userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
}
System.out.println("Input is correct : " + userInput.nextInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
    public static void processInput() {

    System.out.println("Enter only numeric: ");
    Scanner scannerInput;

    while (true) {
        scannerInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (scannerInput.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Entered numeric is " + scannerInput.nextInt());
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error Please Try Again");
        }
    }
}
```